# Can I add my email address on a comment or post?

Tags: discussion, personal-data, email

Is it allowed for a user to add his/her personal email or personal contact details on a comment or a post?

Comment: Not sure about comment or post but you may add in "about me" section like I did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only if it's relevant to the question and most likely it isn't.

Your post needs to contain enough information that it makes sense and is useful without any external resources 5 years later. It also shouldn't contain signatures or tag lines or otherwise tangential information.

It seems unlikely that a personal email address would meet that requirement, but your user profile would be a great place for it if you want to share it.

Comments should be used for the intermediate stages of improving posts. It's conceivable that an email exchange could help that. The system even automatically inserts chat details in some cases. That said if a post needs so much work that emails are required it's a good sign that there migh be other actions to take on the post. (Flag/close)

Comment: Thanks you, If someone add his/her details to the post then is it illegal?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a rule specifically forbidding this, but I would edit it out on sight.

- If it's in the form of a signature, it only clutters up the post: [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)
- If it's to ask for help via email, the only person being helped then is you. If you desire so, you can move a discussion to chat, but preferably all information is visible in the question/answer so future visitors can benefit from it.