# Is it permissible to exchange contact information in a comment if two users wish to correspond off-site?

Tags: discussion

I have seen the related questions such as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251947/can-i-add-my-email-address-on-a-comment-or-post) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed), but this question concerns a quasi-private exchange of information in the form of a comment, with the understanding that any information thus posted is publicly visible.

Comment: Why not use chat for that?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, If you are not in the same time zone, it'd be easier to use a comment. Otherwise I'd have to link to the chat room in a comment anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If people wish to correspond privately, that's entirely up to them. Better than filling up a comment thread with off-topic issues.

As you point out in the question, comments are publicly visible. If they exchange private contact info, it may be read by third parties. We have had a few cases where high-rep users were contacted privately by strangers, and weren't happy about it.

So, the safest thing to do is probably to use a temporary e-mail address, or a channel that can be restricted. For example, Twitter only lets people DM each other if they follow them - so they could follow each other on Twitter, and exchange their private contact info via a DM. That's one way, I'm sure any good SO user can find other ways as well.

So to summarize, I'd say it is perfectly acceptable, but it may be wise to use SE only to establish a private channel through which the *actual* contact info is exchanged.

Answer (score 4):

What two consenting adults do in their own time is none of our business.

But if you come up with a good answer in your private chats make sure you post it back here.