# Asking for help via email

Tags: discussion, flags

I recently saw a post that was very unclear and users were asking for additional information via comments and posting suggestions (no answers). OP then provided his/her email to one of the users posting suggestions asking for help outside of SO for this particular question.  Per this question:  [Can I add my email address on a comment or post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251947/can-i-add-my-email-address-on-a-comment-or-post/251949#251949) it looks like the consensus is that there's no rule forbidding posting your email address in a comment/post, but asking for help and then getting a solution outside of SO means that the community does not benefit.

I flagged the comment as "OTHER" saying that the user shouldn't post this, since they should include the relevant info inside the question for the community to assist them.  This would hopefully assist others in the future.  The question itself isn't very good, but I wasn't sure if I took the right action in this situation.

Here's the post in question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883943/issues-deploying-java-web-applications

Did I do the right thing?  What is the current consensus of the community on this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure your flag is very effective or necessary. You aren't saying what you think should be done if the flag is acted upon. If users need additional help that would be out of scope for SO then they are free to give out their email. As far as it not benefiting SO users, hopefully that person would come back to clean up the question and post an answer or ask the other person to post an answer. That would benefit everyone.

Comment: It's a bit roundabout, but it seems the OP is trying to share the rather large project code via email, instead of something like github.  I'd say the comment itself is fine (it's presumably the user's email shared voluntarily), but it's a symptom of a "too-broad" question lacking specifics.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah i noticed after I flagged it that it was to provide a codebase, but wasn't sure if that was OK.

Comment: It's not ok to have a too broad question (I'm not familiar with the technologies in that question and can't really judge if the OP gave enough information).  It's much better to include the code in the post itself, but trying to share the actual full code off-site (so that the question isn't too long) is fine.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Understood, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an email address to share code outside of the question is a sign that the question is unacceptable:

From the help:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

So it's likely any such question should be closed for being too broad.

On the other hand, Someone might want to continue the discussion about off-topic matters, e.g. "What do you think of this design", additional questions beyond the original one, etc. Posting an email address to allow further 1-2-1 discussion doesn't really hurt the site.